# How can I handle concurrency write on the same row in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

My application is running inside AWS lambda and needs to write to postgresql. There is a scenario that two lambdas will write to the same row in the db table. Below is the case:

Lambda1:
receive order processing event then update order#1 status to `processing`

Lambda2:
receive order completed event then update order#1 status to `completed`.

In above scenario, Lambda1 and Lambda2 can happen in any order. how can I make sure the final status of the `order#1` is `completed` not `processing`?

I can do a query before update, but what happen if the other lambda writes to the table in between?

Comment: Postgres does row level locking for writes like that. As long as lambda1 starts its write first, it will be fine.

Comment: [Locking a specific row in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51002790/174777)

Comment: The problem in my case is that lambda1 and lambda2 may run in different order

Comment: How come lambda2 can run before lambda1? I think this is architecture design issue, not postgresql problem?

Comment: yes, this is architecture design issue. I am using event sourcing design and the events come to my lambda can be in any order. So that I need to fix in my lambda. The question is what is the best way to handle this case?

Comment: Simple: make sure that lambda2 doesn't start before lambda1 completes.

Comment: If you just want to make sure the order, you can write a simple state machine using aws step functions OR if you can invoke them asynchronously, you can use lamda destinations.