# How to select a row, lock it, update it, then select again?

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, sql-update, queue

**I have a table with these 3 columns:**

1. task *(string)*
2. status *(string)*
3. date *(datetime)*

**I want to write a query that does the following:**

1. **Selects** the first row `WHERE status != "In-Progress"` Sorted by Date (oldest first), and **Locks** it - so other computers running this query concurrently can't read it.
2. **Updates** the Status column so `status = "In-Progress"`.
3. Return the row's columns (like a regular `Select *` statement).

How do I write this query?

My main concern is that the row is only fetched by 1 computer, no matter how many concurrent instances are running.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52557413/9705687) shows a method for locking specific rows of a table.

Comment: What do you want to happen to another session that is also running this process in parallel and finds the row locked?

Comment: Ideally I'd like the row to not show up in other queries at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a table named "tbl" with a PK named "tbl_id":

```sql
UPDATE tbl
SET    status = 'In-Progress' 
WHERE  tbl_id = (
         SELECT tbl_id
         FROM   tbl
         WHERE  status <> 'In-Progress'
         ORDER  BY date
         LIMIT  1
         FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
         )
RETURNING *;
```

For an in-depth discussion of every step, see this related answer on dba.SE:

- [Postgres UPDATE ... LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)